# ensure_csrf_cookie on every page

Tags: django, csrf, python-decorators, csrf-protection, django-csrf

Consider an online shop with a Basket button. Clicking the button reveals a popup, where user can change, among other things, number of items to be ordered (AJAX requests).

That means I've got to add `ensure_csrf_cookie` to every page. But some views are defined right in `urls.py` files (e.g., `TemplateView.as_view(...)`). Additionally, I'd like to enforce it for all the pages, to not forget to add it one day. What do I do?

Comment: You can pass the CSRF token with the AJAX request (as a POST parameter), this looks like a better solution than passing it through a cookie.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The question is not about passing CSRF token from client side to the server, but in the [opposite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form) direction.